# Old Firebug suggest html class and ID but new built in firebug don't

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

Firebug for Firefox suggested HTML classes and IDs when adding a new CSS rule:

[image: firebug suggesting html class of h2]

Though the Firefox DevTools don't suggest anything. The developer has to write it by themselves:

[image: Firefox Devtools not suggesting the class of h2].

Is there any way to get that feature in the latest Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not implemented in the Firefox DevTools (as of Firefox 65), though I've created a [feature request for autocompleting classes and IDs within the Rules side panel](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1492797) some time ago.